# SQL query for setting value

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, postgresql-9.4

I would like to use this example for configuration database tables:

[image]

[image]

How I can insert new configuration value into the tables so that the model is preserverd fro examle for value "track"?
And also how I can execute query in order to get the value with all meta data from the tables? I want to implement this model in PostgreSQL and Oracle

Comment: Didn't someone ask this question yesterday?

Comment: Yes, but there are small changes. Can you give some proposal, please?